# Expand dataframe on combination of column

Tags: python, pandas

Can't seem to find the right words to type into Stack Overflow, and I can't find the answer in past code I've written so I have no choice but to ask again.

I am trying to expand my dataframe on all combinations of a certain column:

Note: Pandas ver 23.4

Given the following dataframe

```
name      num
 A       1X,2Y,3Z
 B       1X,2Y,3Z
 C       9Z
```

I am trying to make it:

```
name     num
 A      1X,2Y
 A      1X,3Z
 A      2Y,3Z
 B      1X,2Y
 B      1X,3Z
 B      2Y,3Z
 C        9Z
```

What I (thought) was correct:

```
s = (pd.DataFrame(df.pop('num').values.tolist(), index = df.index)
    .stack()
    .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
    .rename('num')
    .astype(str)
    )

df = df.join(s)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) based approach:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

# split the strings by "," and
# extract all length 2 combinations from the strings
l = df.num.str.split(',').apply(combinations, r=2).map(list)
# construct a dataframe from the result
out = pd.DataFrame({'name':df.name.repeat(l.str.len()), 
                    'num':list(chain.from_iterable(l.values))})
# join the tuples containing each combination
out['num'] = out.num.str.join(', ')

   name   num
0    A  1X, 2Y
0    A  1X, 3Z
0    A  2Y, 3Z
1    B  1X, 2Y
1    B  1X, 3Z
1    B  2Y, 3Z
```

---

**Update**

If there are entries with only one item:

```
l = df.num.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x, r=2)) or x)
nums = chain.from_iterable([map(', '.join, i) if len(i) > 1 else i for i in l])
out = pd.DataFrame({'name':df.name.repeat(l.str.len()), 
                    'num':list(nums)})

  name     num
0    A  1X, 2Y
0    A  1X, 3Z
0    A  2Y, 3Z
1    B  1X, 2Y
1    B  1X, 3Z
1    B  2Y, 3Z
2    C      9Z
```

Comment: Apologies, but this breaks the case where only one value might be present in a row for `num`. I left it out of the question not thinking it would matter.

Comment: Let's try and addapt this answer @MaxB, updating soon